# Laravel round doesn't work, round only to total number

Tags: php, laravel, rounding

In controller in code I have method that return number:

```
$data = [
         'mynumber' => round(2.733, 2)
        ];
return view('pages.admin.buy', $data);
```

and in view I have:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <p>
     aaaa: ${{ $draw->getAttribute('mynumber') }} <br>
```

and it display 3. When I change number to 2.333, it displays 2. How to display numbers rounded to two places after dot?

Comment: AFAIK, Laravel doesn't have helper for rounding. You have to use native php function for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```php
(double)number_format(2.733, 2, ".", "");
```

Full code:

```php
$data = [
    'mynumber' => (double)number_format(2.733, 2, ".", "")
];

return view('pages.admin.buy', $data);
```

More on number_format function: 
1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php 
2. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

Because you are printing it from getAttribute(). Not outputting it from the array.

use this line to output the rounded value.

```
{{ $data['mynumber'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use like that use the number_format in which here 2 indicate the decimal place which you want.
hope it helps

```
{{number_format($booking['Paid'],2)}}
```